# Why did the word "Internet" change from a noncount to count noun?

Tags: british-english, terminology, count

I remember a time back in 1993 - 1994 for a couple months at our university the Internet was used as a noncount noun, so we would say:

> Do you have **Internet** at your university?

In fact, the Internet has a lot of similarities to electricity and we would say:

> Do you have **electricity** in your house?

But gradually other people just started to say "**the Internet**" and so our little group at the university followed suit and never thought about it again.

**Does anyone remember any official journalistic decision on this, or was our group just an early anomaly?**

Comment: Hum, good question. Note that there were still other, non-internet networks like "DecNet" and "BitNet" around the early nineties.

Comment: I actually have no memory of "Internet" ever being correctly or even commonly used as a non-count noun. The word "internet" as a common noun refers to an interconnection of several networks. "The Internet", with both the definite article and capitalized, came, at least informally, to refer to the mass interconnection of hundreds of networks in a single system under a single set of protocol standards.

So "Internet" has really never been a non-count word when correctly used.

Comment: It became suddenly uncool and went out of fashion when GW mentioned "The Google". (http://www.theonion.com/articles/google-launches-the-google-for-older-adults,5850/)

Comment: I think the same person said also "the Internets". `:-)`

Comment: I love "official journalistic decision". Do journalists make the rules?

Comment: @Evan sorry, thinking of the Rechtschreibreform which I guess wouldn't be possible anywhere else: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography_reform_of_1996

Comment: Not to mention the meme of "you, sir, win a hundred (for instance) internets".

Comment: Only time I've heard "internets" is in such phrases as "halp! my internets is broken!"

Comment: Exactly right @cla & @kiam, I think it was around the tech bubble when Internet was broken into the internets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a point of reference, when people say "The Internet" they are referring to a specific network.  When it was first created people used to differentiate between "The Internet" and "an internet" because there were lots of different internets but one of them was special.

In my personal experience people have more recently started saying "Do you have Internet?" because there is only one Internet worth talking about and its existence is assumed, and it has reached the status of a basic utility, like water or electricity or cable.  But "Do you have Internet" is equivalent to saying "Do you have Internet access", and not equivalent to "Do you have The Internet?" which sounds odd, as if you're asking if I possess the Internet.

Comment: "When it was first created people used to differentiate between "The Internet" and "an internet" because there were lots of different internets but one of them was special." - evidence?

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock: No evidence at hand but this Wikipedia article has some info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_capitalization_conventions

Comment: This tallies with my own experience. In the UK, "internet" is used colloquially as a noncount noun when referring to a connection as a utility, while "the internet" is used when referring to the network itself.

Comment: Sounds like you are defining internet in comparison to intranet. Is this actually a question akin to "how did the WWW/http become synonymous with usage of internet?"

Comment: @mfg: Wikipedia states that an intranet is different from an internet in that an intranet is within one organization and an internet is between multiple organizations.

Comment: What is an "organization"? Is it a group of people, that must login through an encrypted secure protocol, who share 140 character updates? Sorry, your answer is vague enough to confuse it with either one. My point is that this answer is all conjecture and you do not clarify between any internets.

Comment: @mfg: An organization is an entity, such as a University or business, which operates a network. So if IBM sets up a network which uses internet technology, but that network is only available within IBM, it is an intranet.  If IBM and Microsoft connect their respective intranets together, they have created an internet.  ONE of the world's internets is THE Internet. This isn't conjecture, this is how the words are used in the computer industry.

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever heard "the internet" and "internet access" used that way, but I *have* heard other networks such as "NIPRnet" used that way.

Comment: Do you mean you hear people say "The NIPRnet" ?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard Internet as a non-count noun mostly from British speakers -- I can't remember ever hearing it that way from Americans.  My guess, then, would be that the American version ("the Internet") became more common and drowned out other forms.

Answer (score 0):

In the mid nineties (summer of 1995, I think) I provided technical assistance to a biology convention at the University of Wisconsin - Madsion.  One of the presentations I helped was about ways to interconnect with other scientists in the discipline and I remember them talking about the "World Wide Web" and "The Internet."  From that point on - my earliest exposure to either term - I've always thought about it as "The Internet."

Answer (score 0):

WIRED magazine switched from "Internet" to "internet" in 2004:
http://www.wired.com/culture/lifestyle/news/2004/08/64596

Comment: Capitalisation has nothing to do with this question. It's all about the "the".

Answer (score -2):

Probably since IPv6 spawned creation of [Internet2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet2) :)

'the internet' would refer to the old, more popular internet, the one with insufficient host address space.

Well, kidding.